# What causes node.js processes the blocking state that removes the multi-threading state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, parallel-processing, fork

I'm trying to make a 'multi-thread' express server that will spawn a process which will execute the task.

The whole idea behind this, would be to refactor my high intensive single thread node.js app, so that I can spawn more processes and therefore have separate intensive tasks running at the same time.

```
// Primary app (master).
// File called: app.js
const express = require('express');
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const app = express();

var counter = 0;
app.post('/intensiveTask', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const forked = fork('./child.js');
        console.log(`forked child: ${++counter}`)
        forked.send(counter);
        forked.on('message', (m) => {
              console.log('from child: ' + m);
              res.sendStatus(200);
              forked.kill();
        });
     } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
        res.json({ error: err.message || err.toString() });
     }
});

try {
    app.listen(8080);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`Failed to start the server due to the following error: ${err}`);
}


// Process app (child).
// File called: child.js

process.on('message', (m) => {
    console.log('inside child: ' + m);

    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5000));
    console.log(`about to wait ${time} for process ${m}`);

    setTimeout(() => {
        process.send(`finish... ${m}`);
    }, time);

});
```

The main issue that i am encountering is related to these results using JMeter:
For 50 threads, I get around 16s.
For 100 threads, I get around 32s.
And the problem is that they all arrive at the same time. I expected to have the first requests coming sooner and not all at the same time at the end. 
So I am wondering what might be the cause of this blocking state...

```
In the begining block: 
...
forked child: 176
forked child: 177
forked child: 178
forked child: 179
...
In the midddle block:
...
about to wait 735 for process 159
about to wait 4475 for process 133
about to wait 518 for process 131
inside childe: 125
about to wait 3909 for process 100
...
At the end, a block of finishing state :
...
from child: finish... 84
from child: finish... 81
from child: finish... 83
from child: finish... 88
...
```

Comment: How are you sending the 100 requests?  Are you 100% sure that the 100 requests are all arriving at your server at about the same time?  Also, do you realize that for CPU-intensive code having more processes than you have cores is not really going to help you much.  In fact, it may even hurt you because the OS scheduler has to spend time switching between all the threads.

Comment: Hey, there is a ramp up time of 1s, but they all arrive to the server.
Actually I get an answer for all of them, the issue is that they all arrive at the same time...

Comment: That's probably just your OS trying to do fair scheduling between all the processes it's running.  You told it to run all those processes at the same time so that's what it's doing and it's trying to share the CPU equally among them all.

Comment: All your  responses are serialized through your one single-threaded node.js process that received the initial requests so you do have a point of serialization there.  And, depending upon how you are logging them at the other end, they may be serialized there too.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what the question is here?  What were you expecting the behavior to be?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the child processes should take care of sending the response back?

Comment: No.  I'm just making comments about your current architecture that leads to serialization of the responses.  And, I'm asking questions about what you are expecting the results to be?

Comment: Ok so basically I was expecting to have some answers before the end of the test. Instead i got all the 100 answers in the last 5-10sec of the whole test that took 32s in total.

Comment: FYI, if you used the node.js clustering module, it does have the child send the response back.  It passes the incoming http socket to the child process so it can send the response.

Comment: Great I will take a look at that module.

Comment: Well, that's expected.  You started 100 processes as close together as possible and your OS will attempt to multi-task among them all to share the CPU equally.

Comment: To put you in context, I have an app that makes pdf out of html using puppeteer, and that task is intensive and it seemed to block the whole process, so I was exploring ways of having multiple tasks running at the same time, and this is the starting point.

Comment: Next time, please put the actual application in your question - not just the theoretical question.  Then, you're more likely to "in-context" advice.  For that type of work, I would think you'd want the job queue like I describe in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fire up 100 processes and ask them all to do the same amount of CPU-intensive work, then your OS is going to attempt to share the CPU among those 100 processes as equally as it can.  That will cause all 100 processes to finish about the same time.

In addition, it is NOT more efficient for the overall system to fire up more worker processes that are all doing CPU-intensive work than you have cores in your CPU because that just creates extra overhead for the OS to constantly be time-slicing between them which detracts from the overall throughput.

If, what you want is for the first tasks that arrive to finish first (significantly before the later ones) and the last ones to finish last, then perhaps what you want for an architecture is a work queue.

You can create as many worker processes as you have cores and you create a queue for incoming work.  When an incoming request arrives, you see if there's a free worker.  If there is, you give the job to the free worker.  If there's no free worker, the request goes in a FIFO queue.  When one of the workers finishes, you then grab the oldest item from the queue and pass that request to the worker than just finished.  This architecture will let the first requests finish sooner and make the later ones wait.  It's also scalable to much larger loads because obviously if you create a new process for every new request, pretty soon you have so many processes that you've consumed a lot of resources on your server (particularly memory) and all the processes are just competing with one another.

Another option for you would be to use the clustering module in node.js.  This will create one process for each CPU core in your system and it will automatically hand off an incoming request to one of those processes, including handing off the actual incoming HTTP connection so that the worker can even send the response for you.

I don't have a particular recommendation, but there are also job queue modules already written for node.js so you could also perhaps use one of those rather than writing your own.

Comment: Any good reference for the clustering module in node that you recommend?

Comment: @PCS-I - Besides the node.js doc for the clustering module, I don't have a particular favorite reference.  There had been a lot written about using it so you can find all sorts of articles with a search.

Comment: @PCS-I - I'd suggest reading this article [CPU Intensive Node.js: Part 1](https://codeburst.io/cpu-intensive-node-js-part-1-1218b102e5ec), both parts 1 and 2.